# Support viewing correctly and creating NSG GPKG RASTER TILES

Tags: leaflet

Trying to view a US Navy Or NGA NSG Geopackage raster tiles in OpenLayers or Leafletjs webmaps
I have used NGA geopackage-js but it NOT been updated to support these NSG spec geopackage that do not use zoom level and column Row numbering like  Google XYZ TOP LEFT ORIGIN or TMS bottom left origin. In addition, they do nkt start with zoom level 0 being one tile. It uses two tiles. samples can be found at https://geoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/#/ or use their download area of interest tool to create a new geopackage. https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-js

Comment: Please tell which sample gpkg to use. Is the Blue marble sample good for testing https://geoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/static/geopackages/NRL_BlackMarble_USA_3-5_v1-0_17OCT2017.gpkg?

Comment: Yes that one is fine

Comment: https://nsgreg.nga.mil/doc/view?i=4462. About NSG PROFILE

Comment: And is the reason for your problem that the first level in the tile matrix is 3 and it has 16 columns and 8 rows? Rows and columns in gpkg are always numbered in fixed order `The tile coordinate (0,0) always refers to the tile in the upper left corner of the tile matrix at any zoom level, regardless of the actual availability of that tile.`

Comment: They are not named like regular gpkg

Comment: http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/    regular gpkg follow the Google tile naming

Comment: Whats the difference? I am sorry but if you know that already you can tell it faster that I can find it out from the data. Do you mean that the tile matrix is different than the tiling schema used in Google maps? There is no "regular gpkg" because it is OK by the standard to use a different tile matrix. It must just be defined in gpkg_tile_matrix_set and gpkg_tile_matrix tables.

Comment: Data opens fine with QGIS so the GeoPackage is valid. The coordinate system is EPSG:4326 which is not the same as in Google maps. The problem is then in how to initialize the NGA viewer to use some other tile matrix than the Google maps compatible schema. I can't answer that but the API seems to have methods for handling different projections and tilematrixsets http://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/jsdoc/module-geoPackage-GeoPackage.html

Comment: Not talking about projection if the tiles load in the wrong place on earth. The Google XYZ has nothing to do with Google maps it's just a specification of tile naming /!numbering versus TMS

Comment: Standard GPKG uses XYZ and MBTILES uses TMS NSG GPKG is a new schema

Comment: Please read the GeoPackage standard and tell where it says anything about "standard XYZ". I agree that NSG is using different schema but it is as much "standard" even if not so "common". Tiling schemas are always tied to some coordinate system. NSG tiles are in this case in EPSG:4326 and renaming the tiles do not make them suit with MBTiles, for example, which is always in EPSG:3857.

Comment: QGIZ and ESRI ARCGIS ARCMAP ARCGIS PRO support NSG PROFILE. I AM working on web application and mobile app.remember unlike.A geotiff that has reference to a location these are plain PNG or JPG.without world files jpw or prj projection it's all about zoom column and.row.z/x/y.jpg like.tile server but instead local database with tiles in tile_,data blob field

Comment: I can't follow you. If you are a developer then you can make your app to resolve the projection and tiling schema from the above mentioned metadata tables just like QGIS and ESRI is doing it and initialize the Leaflet map accordingly. By doing that you know exactly where to place any gpkg png tile when you know the zoom level, row, and column.

Comment: 5/8/13 is Florida in XYZ. In NSG it's not. This goes beyond supporting other Coordinate Systems that GeoPackage already does. Even when you don't use EPSG 3857 you still have the data named the same that how any map client reads it.  NSG is not something you can just make work without some logic on the column an row naming or equivalency to Google XYZ.  The NGA have NOT even updated any of their GITHUB libraries to include support for it.

Answer (score 2):

The NSG GeoPackage spec defines permitted extensions and restrictions on top of the OGC GeoPackage spec.  It does not define base GeoPackage spec breaking changes to how tiles are stored.

*National System for Geospatial-Intelligence (NSG) GeoPackage Encoding Standard 1.1
Interoperability Standard
(2017-08-10)
Version 2.1*

> This Interoperability Standard is a Class 2 conformance profile as defined by ISO 19106, Geographic Information – Profiles date 2004-07-01 that includes a single standard with permitted NSG extensions and restrictions to the standard. An Interoperability Standard provides detailed direction on how to use the clauses, options, and parameters of the base standard(s).

The GeoPackage spec [stores tiles](http://www.geopackage.org/spec120/#tiles) in a tile pyramid which has nothing to do with XYZ tiles (although you can configure a GeoPackage to mirror XYZ tiles).

> The gpkg_tile_matrix_set table defines the spatial reference system (srs_id) and the maximum bounding box (min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y) for all possible tiles in a tile pyramid user data table.
>
> The tile coordinate (0,0) always refers to the tile in the upper left corner of the tile matrix at any zoom level, regardless of the actual availability of that tile.

The NSG GeoPackage spec restricts the tile dimensions to 256x256, zoom levels by a factor of 2, and bounding boxes to represent the full global tile indexing scheme.

> NSG Req 20: The gpkg_tile_matrix table SHALL contain tile_width and tile_height column values of 256 for every table_name tile pyramid data table.
>
> NSG Req 21: Every tile_data tile in every table_name tile pyramid data table shall have a width and height of 256 pixels.
>
> NSG Req 22: The gpkg_tile_matrix table SHALL contain pixel_x_size and pixel_y_size column values that differ by a factor of 2 between all adjacent zoom levels for each tile pyramid data table per OGC GeoPackage Clause 2.2.3.  It SHALL NOT contain pixel sizes that vary by irregular intervals or by regular intervals other than a factor of 2 between adjacent zoom levels per OGC GeoPackage Clause 2.2.3.
>
> NSG Req 23: The (min_x, min_y, max_x,  max_y) values in the gpkg_tile_matrix_set table SHALL be the maximum bounds of the CRS specified for the tile pyramid data table and SHALL be used to determine the geographic position of each tile in the tile pyramid data table.

The [geopackage-js library](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-js) does support NSG GeoPackages since they adhere to the base GeoPackage specification.  I ran through the [U.S. Naval Research Laboratory NSG GeoPackage examples](https://geoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/#/) and all worked [on the geopackage-js demo page](http://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/).  The [Blue Marble GeoPackage](https://geoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/static/geopackages/NRL_BlueMarble-3395_GLOBAL_0-6_v1-0_18OCT2017.gpkg) revealed a bug when using proj4js causing high level tiles and further in edge tiles to not display.  This has now been fixed.  NSG GeoPackages with a SRS organization of NGA are currently not supported ([see this issue](https://github.com/ngageoint/GeoPackage/issues/4) for more details).  Feel free to submit [geopackage-js issues](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-js/issues) if you run into additional problems.

Edit: [Load Black Marble GeoPackage in geopackage-js](http://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/?gpkg=https://geoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/static/geopackages/NRL_BlackMarble_USA_3-5_v1-0_17OCT2017.gpkg&layers=BlackMarble_tiles)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Leaflet Plugin answer: The Leaflet map should be in the EPSG:3857 projection, regardless of the raster layer projections defined in the GeoPackage (the call from the leaflet plugin into geopackage-js is doing raster reprojection to the XYZ spec for EPSG:3857). The call used in the OpenLayers example below does not reproject.

I'm unfamiliar with Leaflet but I can answer this question for OpenLayers.

```
// this all assumes that the variables 'gpkg' and 'tableName'
// are already defined

var tileMatrixToResolution = function(tileMatrix) {
  return tileMatrix ? tileMatrix.pixel_x_size : null;
};

var tileMatrixToTileSize = function(tileMatrix) {
  if (!tileMatrix) {
    return null;
  }

  var h = tileMatrix.tile_height;
  var w = tileMatrix.tile_width;
  return w === h ? w : [w, h];
};

var getTileUrlFunction() {
  var template = tableName + '/{z}/{y}/{x}';
  return function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
    return template.replace('{z}', tileCoord[0].toString()).
        replace('{x}', tileCoord[1].toString()).
        replace('{y}', (-tileCoord[2] - 1).toString());
  };
};

var getTileLoadFunction() {
  return function(imageTile, src) {
    var prevSrc = imageTile.getImage().src;
    if (prevSrc) {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(prevSrc);
      imageTile.getImage().src = '';
    }
    var parts = src.split(/\/+/);
    if (parts.length === 4) {
      var z = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
      var y = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
      var x = parseInt(parts[3], 10);

      gpkg.getTileDaoWithTableName(tableName, function(err, tileDao) {
        if (err) {
          imageTile.state = ol.TileState.ERROR;
          imageTile.changed();
          return;
        }

        tileDao.queryForTile(x, y, z, function(err, tile) {
          if (err) {
            imageTile.state = ol.TileState.ERROR;
            imageTile.changed();
            return;
          }

          if (!tile) {
            imageTile.state = ol.TileState.LOADED;
            imageTile.changed();
            return;
          }

          var array = tile.getTileData();
          var type = // ... determine PNG or JPG data from array;
          var blob = new Blob([array], {type: type});
          imageTile.getImage().src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        });
      });
    }
  };
};

gpkg.getTileDaoWithTableName(tableName, function(err, tileDao) {
  var tileMatrices = tileDao.zoomLevelToTileMatrix;

  gpkg.getInfoForTable(tileDao, function(err, info) {
    var extent = [
      info.tileMatrixSet.minX,
      info.tileMatrixSet.minY,
      info.tileMatrixSet.maxX,
      info.tileMatrixSet.maxY];

    var projection = info.srs.organization.toUpperCase() + ':' +
        (info.srs.organization_coordsys_id || info.srs.id);

    var source = new ol.source.TileImage({
      projection: projection,
      tileLoadFunction: getTileLoadFunction(),
      tileUrlFunction: getTileUrlFunction(),
      tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
        extent: extent,
        minZoom: Math.round(info.minZoom),
        resolutions: tileMatrices.map(tileMatrixToResolution),
        tileSizes: tileMatrices.map(tileMatrixToTileSize)
      });
    });

    // ... create a layer with the source
  });
});
```

I typed this up quickly (not tested) from my full source at https://github.com/wallw-bits/opensphere-plugin-geopackage. You will want to ensure that the projection defined in the GeoPackage is also defined in OpenLayers. OpenLayers ships with EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857 defined already. Additionally, it helps for the map/view to be in the same projection as the imagery to prevent raster reprojection by OpenLayers so what is shown is exactly what was retrieved from the GeoPackage.

Lastly, I decided to use a custom tile class (which I did not include above) which cleans up the blob URL when the tile is disposed.

The example at https://geoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/static/geopackages/NRL_BlackMarble_USA_3-5_v1-0_17OCT2017.gpkg worked perfectly with this approach.

The biggest tip for supporting GeoPackage rasters in other map libraries is to check out that library's support of WMTS, as that seems to be the spec that was the inspiration to GeoPackage's raster tables.